# Tailwind breakpoints not applying correctly

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have building a column system using tailwind and scss (I am using Nuxt 3 too). I wan to add a gap between each columns and for this I am adding a margin right to the children elements. When I am at the end of a row, the last element should not have any margin. Here is my scss for this :

```scss
.content-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    width: 1400px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 80px);

    margin: 0 auto;

    $col-width: calc((100% - 11 * 40px) / 12);

    @for $i from 1 through 12 {
        .col-#{$i} {
            width: calc(#{$i} * #{$col-width} + (#{$i} - 1) * 40px);
            margin-right: 40px;
        }
    }

    .col-1:nth-child(12n + 12) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .col-2:nth-child(6n + 6) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .col-3:nth-child(4n + 4) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .col-4:nth-child(3n + 3) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .col-5:nth-child(2n + 2) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .col-6:nth-child(2n + 2) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .col-12 {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

here is my html code

```html
<section class="image-background mb-1 lg:mb-2">
    <div class="content-container py-10 md:py-15">
        <h1 class="col-12 md:col-10 lg:col-8 mb-1 md:mb-2">{{ service?.data.title }}</h1>
        <p class="col-12 md:col-10 lg:col-8 highlight">{{ service?.data.highlight }}</p>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="py-2 lg:py-4">
    <div class="content-container">
        <PrismicRichText :field="service?.data.description" class="col-12 md:col-10 lg:col-8" />
    </div>
</section>
<section class="py-2 lg:py-4">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="columns-1 gap-gallery md:gap-gallery-md md:columns-2 lg:columns-3">
            <PrismicImage v-for="image of service?.data.gallery" :field="image.image" class="w-full mb-1/2 md:mb-1" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="py-4 lg:py-8">
    <div class="content-container">
        <h2 class="col-12">Services</h2>
        <DetailedService v-for="i of 4" class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4" />
    </div>
</section>
```

As you can see I have multiple sections containing a "content-container", each containing multiple children.

My problem is in the "Services" container. My medium breakpoints nth-child are applying over the large ones. Also, My nth-child are not targeting the right elements (like if the counter was not reset for every container).

Here is a screenshot of the situation :

[image: CSS media query not working]

We can see here that is not even every second child:
[image: Wrong selection using nth-child]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `gap` ? you can set a fixed "margin" between the elements of your flex parent with it

Answer (score 1):

`.content-container .md\:col-6:nth-child(2n+2)` has a higher [specificty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.content-container .md\:col-4`, thus, the property described in the former rule applies over the same properties described in the later one.

Beware the `nth-child` pseudo-class is also counting your `h2` element here, if you want to count only the `div` elements, use `nth-of-type` instead.

Comment: I switched from `nth-child` to `nth-of-type`, but I don't understand how I can increase my specificity in this case. Shouldn't  `lg` take over `md`?

Comment: No, both check for a **minimum** screen size, and the actual screen size satisfies both conditions, so both rules apply. However, one is more specific than the other, so it overwrites it. The _pseduo-class_ `:nth-child` adds specifity to the first one. If you want to add specifity to the other, you could write it as `:nth-child(n)`. Then both rules will be as specific, and it will be the one that is written last in your CSS file that applies.

Comment: First of all, thank you! To solve my problem I used tailwind's `max-[screen size]`. It basically sets a max screen width so both rules do not apply at the same time.